# My coding no funct with useEffect in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, useeffect

Tengo un código que hace una petición fetch (api de pokemon) y me devuelve un array vacío pero, en el segundo renderizado, es decir, cuando el componente se renderiza por segunda vez **sin recargar la página** (solo guardando el código), se muestra el array con los resultados. El problema es que quiero mostrarlos cuando react renderiza el componente por 1ra vez, de forma "normal".

Código:

```javascript
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const pokeApi = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon`);
    const data = await res.json();

    return data.results;
}


const AddPokemon = () => {
    const [pokemonObjet, setPokemonObjet] = useState([]);
    const Data = async () => {
        let data = await pokeApi();
        setPokemonObjet(data);
        console.log(pokemonObjet); //Return array[0] 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        Data();
        console.log(pokemonObjet); // here too
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Pokemon </h1>
        </>)
}

export default AddPokemon;
```

Comment: En la funcion Data, intenta esto: setPokemonObjet([...pokemonObjet, data]);

Comment: Estamos en [es.so], por lo tanto el título como el cuerpo de la pregunta deben ir _solo en español_. Traduce el título. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Lo puedo solucionar, era porque tenía activado el <React.StricMode> al momento de renderizar, por eso se mostraba dos veces. Gracias!!